# Align 4 divs to be 2 per row at smaller viewport widths

Tags: html, css

I have 4 `div`s aligned horizontally from left to right. Each `div` is 25% width of the screen.

I need to make them wrap when the user minimizes the screen instead of glitching above each other.

```css
.MenuSett {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 120px;
  color: #0ddF00;
  display: inline-block;
}

.m1 {
  width: 25%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="MenuSett">

  <div class="m1">
    <p>This content is ok</p>
    <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropdown</button>
      <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
        <button ngbDropdownItem>Action - 1</button>
        <button ngbDropdownItem>Another Action</button>
        <button ngbDropdownItem>Something else is here</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="m1">
    <p>This content is ok</p>
    <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropdown</button>
      <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
        <button ngbDropdownItem>Action - 1</button>
        <button ngbDropdownItem>Another Action</button>
        <button ngbDropdownItem>Something else is here</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="m1">
    <p>This content is ok</p>
    <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropdown</button>
      <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
        <button ngbDropdownItem>Action - 1</button>
        <button ngbDropdownItem>Another Action</button>
        <button ngbDropdownItem>Something else is here</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="m1">
    <p>This content is ok</p>
    <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropdown</button>
      <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
        <button ngbDropdownItem>Action - 1</button>
        <button ngbDropdownItem>Another Action</button>
        <button ngbDropdownItem>Something else is here</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Below that div there is

```
.belowDiv {   
   position: relative;  
   height:350px;
 }
```

How to push it down when the div above wraps ?????

Comment: Your HTML and CSS do not match. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we may help you.

Comment: @khan edited ....... site needs me to add garbage text as code is too many it doesnt allow save

Answer (score 2):

if you want them to be below each other you display flex in parent with `flex-direction: row;` and media queries change flex-direction to column 
`flex-direction: column;`

```
.MenuSett{  
  margin-top:10px ;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative; 
  height: 120px;  
  color: #0ddF00;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; 
} 

.m1 { 
   width: 25%;   
   margin: auto;
   text-align: center;    
   float: left;
} 


@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .MenuSett{ 
    flex-direction: column; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use flex:

```
.MenuSett{  
  margin-top:10px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative; 
  height: 120px;  
  color: #0ddF00;
  display: inline-block;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
} 

.m1 { 
   flex: 1; 
   margin: auto;
   text-align: center;    
   float: left;
}
```

The parent `.MenuSett` would have `display: flex;`, `flex-direction: row;` & `flex-wrap: wrap;` and the children `.m1` would have `flex: 1` and without the width set.

But you might also do some media queries as at some minimal screen width having 4 columns at the same time could be too much. Like this ones:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .m1 { 
   flex: 1 0 100%;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .m1 { 
    flex: 1 0 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .m1 { 
    flex: 1 0 25%;
  }
}
```

Comment: hi thanks this makes them not to glitch but the items doesn't go in other row

Comment: What do you mean with other row?

Comment: i mean to wrap 2 items up and the 2 others below them like grid when screen width is minimum

Answer (score 1):

You can add Flexbox to `.MenuSett` and use `flex-wrap: wrap` to get its children to go onto a new line at smaller viewport widths.

Note that you would need to set an absolute value for the width, such as `250px`. This is because with `width: 25%`, regardless of the viewport width, the children will always be 25% of its parent, thus always displaying them on one row.

```css
.MenuSett {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 120px;
  color: #0ddF00;
  
  /* Introduce Flexbox to parent */
  display: flex;
  
  /* Allow children to wrap to the next line */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.m1 {
  /* At larger viewports, children will be 25% of parent */
  width: 25%;
  
  /* At viewports smaller than ~1000px, children will start
     wrapping because they have a minimum width set. Change
     this value as needed. */
  min-width: 250px;
  
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="MenuSett">

  <div class="m1">
    <p>This content is ok</p>
    <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropdown</button>
      <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
        <button ngbDropdownItem>Action - 1</button>
        <button ngbDropdownItem>Another Action</button>
        <button ngbDropdownItem>Something else is here</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="m1">
    <p>This content is ok</p>
    <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropdown</button>
      <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
        <button ngbDropdownItem>Action - 1</button>
        <button ngbDropdownItem>Another Action</button>
        <button ngbDropdownItem>Something else is here</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="m1">
    <p>This content is ok</p>
    <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropdown</button>
      <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
        <button ngbDropdownItem>Action - 1</button>
        <button ngbDropdownItem>Another Action</button>
        <button ngbDropdownItem>Something else is here</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="m1">
    <p>This content is ok</p>
    <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropdown</button>
      <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
        <button ngbDropdownItem>Action - 1</button>
        <button ngbDropdownItem>Another Action</button>
        <button ngbDropdownItem>Something else is here</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: this does what i need but now it collapses with bottom div and shows content above it how can i push it down also ???

Comment: That wasn't included in your question. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on how to create a minimal, reproducible, complete example.

Comment: i didn't know that the answer won't make it pushed down

Comment: khan this is the last issue i have

Comment: If there are other children in `.MenuSett`, then Flexbox will affect them as well. You can read more on Flexbox [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox). It's a really useful tool for front-end design.

Comment: khan thanks i fixed it by adding top margin inside media

Comment: khan can i set this to percentage like `media (max-width: 25%)` ??? instead of static px

Comment: If you're asking if you can do `@media screen and (max-width: 25%) { ... }`, then no, you can't use percentages in your media query. It wouldn't make sense because the viewport width is always 100%.